# Set SharedPreference in Authenticator?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using Android. I store my auth token using `SharedPreferences`.

In order to refresh auth tokens, I use the `Authenticator` class.

Now, I need to be able to set the new auth token in the `SharedPreferences`, however, in order to do this, `SharedPreferences` requires a context.

How can I set the new (refreshed) auth token from the `Authenticator` class when I don't have a context?

Here is my Authenticator class:

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    private String authToken;

    public TokenAuthenticator(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (responseCount(response) >= 3) {
            return null;
        }

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class, authToken);
        Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.refreshAuthToken();
        BasicResponse apiResponse = call.execute().body();

        String newToken = apiResponse.getData().getToken();

        // Set the new token in shared preferences (how to get context?)
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putString("AUTH_TOKEN", token).apply();

        return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + newToken)
                .build();
    }

    private int responseCount(Response response) {
        int result = 1;
        while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

And here is where the Authenticator class is called from:

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String API_URL = "http://www.user324211.com/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (authToken != null) {
            TokenAuthenticator tokenAuthenticator = new TokenAuthenticator(authToken);
            httpClient.authenticator(tokenAuthenticator);
        }

        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        retrofit = builder.build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you create instances of `TokenAuthenticator`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Added the code.

Comment: Where do you call createService()?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice All over my app whenever I need to get data from my server. In my code above, it's used in the `TokenAuthenticator` class.

Comment: "In my code above, it's used in the `TokenAuthenticator` class." I am confused. Where does `TokenAuthenticator` use `ApiClient.createService()`? I do not see that in the code you posted. From what I see the dependency is the other way around. Now we need to go up a level. Who calls `getService()`?

Comment: We can keep going up the call stack. Eventually, we will find a method in an activity subclass. You can fix the problem by passing a reference of the activity as a context to where it is needed.

Comment: The full line that's called in `TokenAuthenticator` is `ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class, authToken);`.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. Still, this is a circular reference that does not help solve the problem. Please give another example of a class and method which calls `createService()`.

Answer (score 2):

just add 1 more param

```
public TokenAuthenticator(Context context,String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
        this.mContext = context;
}
```

usage

```
TokenAuthenticator tA = new TokenAuthenticator(this,YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

#### EDIT

if no context call, just pass SharedPreferences instead

```
public TokenAuthenticator(SharedPreferences shared,String authToken) {
       this.authToken = authToken;
       this.mShared = shared;
}
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing an example of how to use this constructor.

Comment: A little bit better. You should show what class and method contains this last line of code so that it is clear what `this` is.

Comment: @ZeroOne Unfortunately, the authenticator class is called from a class where no context is given as well.

Comment: maybe you could pass SharedPReferences as param

Comment: "maybe you could pass SharedPReferences as param" this might be a good solution. The OP will still need to figure out whet to get a SharedPreferences reference to pass to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few way to do this

I suggest you create an Application class and create a method inside app
call it **getContext()** then that method is accessible from everywhere

you could get context like **App.getContext()**

Example

```
package YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class App extends Application
{
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context GetContext()
    {
        return context;
    }
}
```

You could make a singleton sharedpreference like this

https://github.com/BioGram/Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/biogram/main/handler/SharedHandler.java

Comment: `static` variables are rarely the correct solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, you are right, but this is Application class so that static variable can't be leaked

Comment: Leaks are the least important issue. I'm more concerned with teaching proper coding practices.

Comment: This is a global solution and in a large app this may be required xD

Comment: static is never "required". You can always pass parameters instead.

Comment: This will cause memory leaks and I'd rather avoid this.

Comment: @user324211, That solution will allow you to have **Context** everywhere

Comment: You are right, this is an easy solution. Generally, static causes more problems than it is worth.